# How to change the style of the braces around equation numbers in the align-environment

Tags: formatting, align, braces

I would like to change the braces in the align-environment from the normal braces ( ) to rectangular braces [ ],

[image: align-environment with the standard ( )-braces.]

Comment: i've changed the title of this question because the equation numbers, strictly speaking, aren't part of the `align` environment.  also, these delimiters aren't braces, but parentheses; i didn't change that though, since the image makes it clear what is really wanted.  however, the tags aren't really appropriate, but i can't find or think of existing ones that are.  ("equation-number" isn't offered.)  so someone else should do that so that this question can be found by other people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this on a one-off basis as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\sqtag{\stepcounter{equation}\tag*{[\theequation]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
a &=b \sqtag \\
  &=c \sqtag 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, try this if you want labels in square brackets for all equations throughout the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@ {[\ignorespaces #1\unskip \@@italiccorr ]}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &=b \\       
  &= c
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know you know this, but the OP may not: The code above changes the style of *all* equation numbers, not just of those that occur in an `align` environment.

Comment: Dear Ian, thanks a lot! This is very good : ) Is it also possible to change the number it displays? I mean, that it could display [0.5] for example? I know the question is a bit weird, but I want to use it to show how many points a student will get for each line in an exam : )

Comment: @AnnaChristine --- you can put `\tag*{whatever}` in the equation (similar to the first example code in my (edited) answer).

Comment: @Mico --- Good point. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @AnnaChristine: For this purpose you should take a look at either the »[exam](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam)« class or a package like »[exsheets](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)«.

Answer (score 6):

The »[mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)« package (from the »[mh](http://ctan.org/pkg/mh)« bundle) provides a quite elegant way to do this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«
\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    (a+b)^2 &= a^2+2ab+b^2 \\
    (a-b)^2 &= a^2-2ab+b^2 \\
    (a+b)(a-b) &= a^2-b^2
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

If you want to switch back to the default setting, just write `\usetagform{default}` where you need it. You can use `\usetagform` with the tag format of your choice wherever you want it in the document.

---

[image]

Comment: Dear Thorsten, thanks a lot for your answer! I chose the other solution as the answer, since it doesn't need an additional package (this is important, since my co-workers might not want to load another package : ))